# XSLT combination from two lists

Tags: xslt

Ive got a list of values in A, and a list of values in B.
I want to output the values of A, (or repeat) for the amount of values in B. Thus if we have 4 values in B, we repeat the 3 values in A, 4 times.

ex

```
  <a>
   <v>1</v>
   <v>2</v>
   <v>3</v>
  </a>
  <b>
   <v>y</v>
   <v>z</v>
  </b>
```

should result into

```
  <x>1</x>
  <x>2</x>
  <x>3</x>
  <x>1</x>
  <x>2</x>
  <x>3</x>
```

this is what I've tried

```
  <xsl:foreach select="a/v">
    <xsl:foreach select="b/v">
      <x><xsl:value-of select="."></x>
    </xsl:foreach>
  </xsl:foreach>
```

Comment: how about `count("a/v")`? Like <xsl:variable name="avcount" select="count('a/v')"/> and then <xsl:foreach select="b/v"> <xsl:if test="position()<=$avcount"/>

Comment: In fact you can do the position() check in the select of the foreach

Comment: @Neijwiert in that case how do you select the value of "a/v"?

Comment: Not 100% sure but try this: <xsl:variable name="curPosition" select="position()"/> and then this selector: "../../a/v[position()=$curPosition]"

Comment: "*I want to output the values of B, for the amount of values in A.*" I am afraid that's not clear enough - especially since you show an output that contains the values of `a`. Please explain the required logic in more detail.

Comment: @michael.hor257k better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a well-formed input:

**XML**

```
<root>
  <a>
    <v>1</v>
    <v>2</v>
    <v>3</v>
  </a>
  <b>
    <v>y</v>
    <v>z</v>
  </b>
</root>
```

the following stylesheet:

**XST 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="b/v">
            <xsl:for-each select="/root/a/v">
                <x><xsl:value-of select="."/></x>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will return:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <x>1</x>
  <x>2</x>
  <x>3</x>
  <x>1</x>
  <x>2</x>
  <x>3</x>
</root>
```

A slightly more efficient version:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:variable name="a">
        <xsl:for-each select="a/v">
            <x><xsl:value-of select="."/></x>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="b/v">
            <xsl:copy-of select="$a"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Given input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <a>
    <v>1</v>
    <v>2</v>
    <v>3</v>
  </a>
  <b>
    <v>y</v>
    <v>z</v>
  </b>
</root>
```

And the 1.0 XSLT stylesheet:

```
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="b/v"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="b/v">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="../../a/v"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="a/v">
  <x><xsl:value-of select="."/></x>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Gives output:

```
123123
```

Best to avoid using `for-each` loops and use templates instead.